# Не получается поставить картинку как фон

Tags: css

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: red;
  background: red url("C:\Users\Оксана\Desktop\тренировка\project\img\keks-background-dark.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую почитать про [ссылки, абсолютные и относительные пути](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_HTML/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA#%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_URL-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC).

Используйте относительные пути к файлам.

```
body {
 background: red url("./img/keks-background-dark.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: red url("C:\Users\Оксана\Desktop\тренировка\project\img\keks-background-dark.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
```

Если вы указываете помимо остальных атрибутов цвет фона, его нужно указывать в последнюю очередь.
Правильно будет

```
background: url("C:\Users\Оксана\Desktop\тренировка\project\img\keks-background-dark.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0 red;
```